# leafletjs : Highlight polyline on mouseover

Tags: leaflet, highlight, polyline

I have an array of polylines that displayed on a map, now what I am aiming to do is, when I hover over a certain polyline from the list, only that polyline highlights (or changes color).

What I have right now is something like this (this code is inside a loop that goes to the end filling polyLineArray with individual polyline data,

```
var pointList = [];

// pointList is an array and lat/lngs

var polyLineProperties = {
    color: 'red',
    opacity: 1,
    weight: 5,
    clickable: true
}

var polyLine = new L.polyline(pointList, polyLineProperties);
polyLine.on('mouseover', function() {
    // WHAT TO DO HERE to HIGHLIGHT that specific polyline.
});

polyLineArray.push(polyLine);
```

How to alter any property of a polyline and not just color?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay,

Sorry but I've managed to figure this one out, thanks to the tutorial on the following link,

[Interactive Choropleth Map](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html)

This is all that was required,

```
polyLine.on('mouseover', function(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        color: 'blue',
        opacity: 1,
        weight: 5
    });
});
```

Thank you all for reading.